# Limit the number of managed metadata column values

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata

How can I limit the number of values that can be used in a managed metadata column?

I would like to implement a restriction similar to StackExchange, where an entry can have a maximum of **5** tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with custom event receiver: ItemAdding and ItemUpdating. Just cut all tags after 5.

Comment: I would also go for item updating, but I would tell the user that there are to many tags by passing back an error message.

Comment: I think it is better to inform user about that in the description of the metadata field.

Comment: I think that should also be done, but users have to be treated as if they didn't see the warnings when you are working usability.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without creating custom code?

Comment: I suppose, not.